# How to get syscall table address with eBPF (BCC)

Tags: ebpf, bcc, bcc-bpf

I want to use Kprobe in eBPF to fetch the syscall addresses from the syscall table. How can I perform this task?

I wrote, but I do not know how to find the symbol table corresponding to the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this:

1. Use the bpf_probe_read() function to read the syscall table from memory.
2. Use the bpf_kprobe__read() function to read the syscall table from the kernel's kprobes.
3. Use the bpf_usdt_read() function to read the syscall table from the kernel's USDT probes.